# Looking for a book where computers communicate with dead souls

Tags: story-identification, computers, souls

About 12 years ago I read a book about a new form of computing (quantum computer) and the ability to use these to communicate with the soul.  I cannot for the life of me remember the title, but I can remember aspects.

In the book there is a religious opposition to the use of the computers, but ultimately the computer gets used to communicate with a dead person's soul and witness the 'afterlife'... I only remember sketchy parts but I am sure at the end the person whose soul links with the computer sees 'hell' or 'the devil'... or something like that... I also think the name of The book has the word 'light' in it..

Please please please can you help me identify the book?

Comment: The first part of your question reminds me of Philip Pullman's `His Dark Materials` trilogy, particularly the second book `The Subtle Knife`, but it doesn't really fit the rest of your question.

Answer (score 2):

[The Lucifer Code](http://www.bookdepository.com/Lucifer-Code-Michael-Cordy/9780552154475) by [Michael Cordy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Cordy)?

*"What happens to us when we die? Oblivion.Or so believes Dr Miles Fleming, a brilliant, young neuroscientist who has developed a device capable of reading human brainwaves. But when his own brother contacts him after being certified dead for six whole minutes, Fleming wonders if he's got it all wrong. His search for the truth uncovers a terrifying religious conspiracy to stage the most ambitious experiment the world has ever seen - to prove beyond doubt the existence of a heaven or a hell. As the world awaits the final judgement, Fleming must confront his own demons to save not only his own soul but that of all humanity. THE LUCIFER CODE pits the faith of religion against the certainty of science in a heartstopping thriller which explores our deepest fears."*

From memory, the book has the Catholic Church splitting, with a Red Pope and a White Pope. The Red Pope is chasing the neurosurgeon for his own purposes while the White Pope wants to destroy the research and technology.

I remember enjoying the book, but not as much as some of Cordy's other books. At one point I owned several but I have since given them away.

> I also think the name of The book has the word 'light' in it

Lucifer is the light-bringer. :-)

Comment: Yes! You're right! Thank you! I found this book completely compelling.