# Book where the Catholic Church was split into factions, one led by a purple Pope

Tags: story-identification, novel

I recall reading a sci-fi novel some years ago. The story goes like this: science has discovered a way to track a dead person's consciousness  through some quantum mechanics trickery. Meanwhile the Catholic Church has split into factions where one is led by a purple Pope. Does anyone know what book this was?

Comment: Could it The Lucifer Code by Michael Cordy as seen in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99577/looking-for-a-book-where-computers-communicate-with-dead-souls? It too has quantum computers to talk to dead people and the answer speaks of "a Red Pope and a White Pope".

Comment: Or if that's not it, Greg Bear's _Heads_ features a way to read minds of dead people. And much religion. No coloured pope though.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from my comment above, someone else posted an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99577/looking-for-a-book-where-computers-communicate-with-dead-souls) that sounds like a match, *[The Lucifer Code](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/857546.The_Lucifer_Code)* by [Michael Cordy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Cordy).

[image: Front cover of The Lucifer Code]

> What happens to us when we die?
>
> Oblivion. Or so believes Dr Miles Fleming, a brilliant, young neuroscientist who has developed a device capable of reading human brainwaves. But when his own brother contacts him after being certified dead for six whole minutes, Fleming wonders if he's got it all wrong.
>
> His search for the truth uncovers a terrifying religious conspiracy to stage the most ambitious experiment the world has ever seen - to prove beyond doubt the existence of a heaven or a hell. As the world awaits the final judgement, Fleming must confront his own demons to save not only his own soul but that of all humanity.

It doesn't have a purple Pope, but it does have a [Red Pope](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=436).

Comment: It's the Michael Cordy book I was thinking of! Thanks!

Comment: :) If so, please click the green checkmark under the voting buttons to accept.